# USB Device connectivity in Android

Tags: android, usb, apk

In my Android project I need to open the application automatically when it detect a usb device with particular Vendorid and Productid.It works fine during the first time when I connect the USB device. But when I unplug and plug it again that app is not restarting. I don't know what is the issue. My manifest code is

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android have USB accessory APIs *(android.hardware.usb)* in which you can get when any USB device attach or detach from android device and add

to manifest and this intent filter to

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

to activity in manifest

```
UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
```

from this you can get system service for USB

```
UsbAccessory[] accessories = mUsbManager.getAccessoryList();
```

You will get a list of currently attached USB accessories. it reports its manufacturer and model names, the version of the accessory, and a user visible description of the accessory to the device.

```
HashMap<String,UsbDevice> result= mUsbManager.getDeviceList()
```

Returns a HashMap containing all USB devices currently attached. USB device name is the key for the returned HashMap. And UsbDevice contains manufacturer and model names, the version etc.

Add Broadcast receiver to activity. This receiver monitors for the event of a user granting permission to use the attached accessory.  If the user has checked to always allow, this will be generated following attachment without further user interaction.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    openAccessory(accessory);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for accessory "+ accessory);
                }
                mPermissionRequestPending = false;
            }
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
            if (accessory != null && accessory.equals(mAccessory)) {
                closeAccessory();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

For more detailed description Read [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory#java)